# How can I start from page 1 again, on the 4th page of my MS Word document?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word

Let's say I have 10 pages on my MS word file.

For the first 3 pages, I want it to be: 1, 2, 3.
For the last 7 pages, I want it to be: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

How do I do that?
Right now, it's just 1 to 10...

Answer (score 3):

I have an older copy of MS Word (2002) on this machine I am writing from, so this might not be exactly the same as for newer versions -- but in my copy, I would do this --

At the top of the fourth page, insert a Section Break (Insert... Break ... Section type: Next page).

Then go to View... Header and Footer, go to Footer on the bottom of the page, highlight the page number and then click on the little icon labeled Format Page Number in the toolbar, it gives me the option of Continue with previous section, or Start At a new page number (which you can set back at 1 again).

Comment: In Word 2007/2010 the "insert break" (for section breaks) is on the page layout tab.